# How to make sub level in DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to make Sub-level in DropdownButton like this ?

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What does your code look like?

Comment: I'm seeing numerous hits when googling for "multilevel dropdownbutton flutter".  Might try some ideas from those.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for your response, yes there is a lot but It is  about dependant dropdowns (EX: 2 ) not in the same dropdownbutton

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795584/flutter-web-need-menu-with-sub-menu May help you a bit...