# Is there a way to display a drop-down on mouse hover in flutter web

Tags: flutter

I am facing a difficulty in implementing a feature using flutter web.[this is the feature i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qetVg.jpg)

Comment: I've added a basic code in the answer section. Consider to up vote and mark as answer if it helps

Comment: @rosh-dev i tried your solution but its not giving me the required feature.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Get a basic idea about drop down from following code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  GlobalKey menuKey = GlobalKey();

  showMenus(BuildContext context) async {
    final render = menuKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
          render.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx,
          render.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy + 50,
          double.infinity,
          double.infinity),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Create a website"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Top Ms commericial management"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Mobile inventory application"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: menuKey,
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: 100,
        minHeight: 50,
      ),
      child: MouseRegion(
        onHover: (event) => showMenus(context),
        child: Text('Solutions'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: will  the pop up menu show below the desired widget?

Comment: answer edited to show below a widget

Comment: yah its working, thanks but the only issue is the menu doesn't close on its own, i need to click outside to close it. Is there any way to achieve this. It would be of great help.

Comment: i mean what i am trying to achieve is a top navigation bar for a website where there will be a menu which on hover will display its sub menu and will close automatically if we move away, i mean its a very common feature of every website but im not able to implement that using flutter web

Comment: you better try a package like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_menu and check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795584/flutter-web-need-menu-with-sub-menu

Comment: Do you have any ans how to hide this menu?