# Create nested menu like web in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

[image: Nested (nth level) menu like web]

I am working on a website using flutter.I want to provide **Menu functionality like web** provide when user **hover mouse on menu** in header bar show the options to select like showing in the above image.

Is there any way to implement Nested (nth level) menu functionality in flutter for web.

Comment: Hi, is there any progress or updates on this?

Comment: Check this one, it might help: [Flutter Web: Need menu with sub menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795584/flutter-web-need-menu-with-sub-menu)